# Java Error: NullPointerException due to missing Constructor(s)

Tags: java, methods, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to access a method within another class, but I already have some constructors in said class which is throwing up an error when I try to create an instance in another class.

**EDIT:** I know I need to fill in a constructor, but I don't know what to put in it. Do I create another JFrame in the ArrayControl class or what?

This is the error I get when I run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Position.ArrayControl.updatePosition(ArrayControl.java:10)
at Display.Display.<init>(Display.java:39)
at Main.Game.<init>(Game.java:19)
at Main.Launch.main(Launch.java:6)
```

This is where the error happens:

```
public class ArrayControl{
 Display display = new Display(); // Error here asking for a JFrame or String, int, int 

public void updatePosition(String name, int x, int y){
    display.updateGrid(name, x, y, display.getGrid());
    }
}
```

The "Display" class I'm trying to access:

```
public class Display {
public JPanel panel = new JPanel();
public ArrayControl arrayC = new ArrayControl();
public JFrame frame;
JLabel[][] grid= new JLabel[5][5];

public JFrame getFrame() {
    return frame;
}

public Display(JFrame frame){
    this.frame = frame;
}

private String title;
private int width, height;
Color sky = new Color(137, 182, 255);
Color enemyPortal = new Color(154, 91, 193);


//Creating a display function that takes in a title, the width (pixels) and height (pixels)
public Display(String title, int width, int height){
    this.title = title;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    createDisplay();
    arrayC.updatePosition("Test", 2, 3);
}
```

I realise this may be a silly question and the answer is glaring me in the face, but all help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Surely you want to pass your instance of Display to ArrayControl, as you don't want to update a different Display, or do you? I doubt this is the case, so in your Display class pass the current instance of Display using `this` to a constructor of ArrayControl that accepts a Display object as a parameter and assigns the Display object passed to the field `display` inside ArrayControl.

Comment: Your assumption is correct! I don't want to update a different display. I'm unsure as to how to do this, fiddling around with the idea just gave me stack overflow errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you identified, the error is here in your `ArrayControl` class:

```
Display display = new Display();
```

The class `Display` does not have a parameterless constructor.

However, as ascertained from the comments, even fixing this will not fix your program.

Currently your `ArrayControl` class is constructing a new instance of `Display` (erroneously), and trying to update on the instance of `Display` stored in the field `display` in your `ArrayControl` class. This is not what you want to do, rather you want to update the instance of `Display` that instanstiated the `ArrayControl` object.

To achieve this you need to pass the current instance of `Display` to `ArrayControl` for it to use. For example (simplified):

```
public class Display {
    private ArrayControl arrayControl;

    public Display() {
        // Pass this instance of Display to ArrayControl to use
        arrayControl = new ArrayControl(this);
        arrayControl.updatePosition("Test", 2, 3);
    }

    public void updateGrid(String name, int x, int y) {
        // Do update grid stuff
    }

}

public class ArrayControl {

    private Display display;

    public ArrayControl(Display display) {
        this.display = display; // assign instance of Display to the field display
    }

    public void updatePosition(String name, int x, int y) {
        display.updateGrid(name, x, y);
        // I'm not sure why you want to pass the display back to the
        // Display class as in your example so I removed it
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what your larger goal is, and why there is an `ArrayControl` class. I assume there is more to it, removed from the question.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem completely. Thanks for making my first question on StackOverflow worth while!

Answer (score 0):

You created a constructor

`public Display(JFrame frame){
    this.frame = frame;
}`

but didn't fill in the constructor (JFrame) when creating an display object.

Comment: I'm aware of that, sorry I didn't explain it enough, I'll edit the question. I know I need to fill in the constructor, but I don't know what to fill it in with, do I create ANOTHER JFrame? That's the part I'm stumped on. Thanks for the fast response

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `arrayC.updatePosition` from `Display`'s constructor, at which point `arrayC.display` is still `null`, because the instance that it is supposed to be assigned to is, well, still under construction.

Answer (score 0):

In Java the default constructor (the one without any argument) appears only if no other constructor is specified. Since you wrote your own constructor:

```
public Display(JFrame frame){
    this.frame = frame;
}
```

You cannot call *new Display()* now.
You can either:

1. Create a JFrame in ArrayControl class and Call *new Display(jFrame);*
2. Create a new constructor without arguments in Display class:

   ```
   public Display() { //do nothing or maybe create JFrame here? }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If a java class is written without declaring any explicit constructors, it has a default, no-arguments constructor. However, if at least a constructor is declared explicitly, then the no-argument constructor is not present by default, and needs to be added if needed. In your case you have a `Display(String title, int width, int height)` constructor, hence the no-argument constructor has to be declared explicitly if needed.

This said, you have a constructor for `Display` calling `arrayC.updatePosition()`, which in turn creates another, distinct display object. That doesn't smell right. I suspect you want a single `Display` instance. I would create a separate method instantiating display, then instantiating all other objects that need to have a reference to it passing it as argument to their constructors.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm not the most experienced coder. I'm unsure on how to go about doing what you suggested. The display method you mentioned is being called in the main class of my program.

Comment: *EDIT*
I attempted to follow your instructions as best I could, I created a seperate method for instantiating display, updated all relevant calls to it and I'm now left with the default no-args constructor. However I'm getting a StackOverflow error which can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/UHBL0sqC
Greatly appreciate your help thus far.

Comment: you're still instantiating `Position.ArrayControl` from `Display`'s constructor, and in there you're instantiating a new `Display`. If both Display and ArrayControl need to refer to each other, I would do:
`myNewMethod() {
   Display d = new Display();